# Scroll tracking & bounce rate & Adwords QS

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

Would GA not count as a bounce if a scroll tracking event was sent from my landing page?

We currently have a simple ecommerce site selling 1 item therefore most of all the necessary info (testimonials, product description...etc) is on the very first page as a scroll down. There are a few separate pages (contact, about..etc) however with most of it being on the first page, my bounce rate is very high.

My main concern at this point is the high bounce rate is negatively effecting my Adwords Quality Score.

If I added a scroll tracking event on my landing page and visitors scroll down to a certain percentage, would GA not count it as a bounce?

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: If you add scroll tracking as **non interaction event** then ***it wont impact bounce rate***

Comment: Your quality score is not affected by bounce rate.   You can certainly add an interactive event (as opposed to non-interactive) and bring the bounce rate down, but you won't really be solving for your main concern, quality score.

Answer (score 0):

An event in Google Analytics will have an effect on your bounce rate, based on its non-interaction flag parameter. This is an optional parameter, and by default it is set to false, meaning event will count as interactive, and sessions with interactive events will not be counted as bounced sessions. For further details and explanations you can read through [this support article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068#NonInteractionEvents).

The Google Analytics [developers guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events#non_interaction_events) will show you the details, how to set this so called non-interaction flag of events, which will control this behavior. By default, without setting non-interaction flag to true, events will count as interactive, and will reduce bounce rate.